# routing works in localhost but not in online host in codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI, please help me to fix it.

routing  works in localhost  but not in online host in codeigniter project

**config.php**

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['test'] = 'test';
```

**Controller** --
**test.php**

```
class test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hi! This is at test";
    }
}
```

**Problem is**

http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/index.php/test   ----- works

http://codeignitertests.site50.net/index.php/test  ------do not work

Answer (score 1):

When you make a controller the class and file names must have there first letter upper case

> Test.php

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
       echo "Working";
    }
}
```

As in previous version was not issue but now in CI3 versions you must have first letter of all class and file names upper case.

For example also when calling model.

> Test_model.php

```
<?php

class Test_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get() {
       // some db stuff here.
    }
}
```

Loading model on to controller

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('test_model');
    }

    public function index() {

       $data['test_results'] = $this->test_model->get();
       $this->load->view('test_page', $data);
    }
}
```

With your base_url you can leave blank if you need to and should pick up your URL automatic

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```